# different types of iterators in cpp

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

As we know there are many types of iterators in cpp like forward iterators, 
output iterator, input iterator, random access iterator but when we declare

```
set<int>::iterator it;
```

1. what type of iterator is that is it the iterator of some kind mentioned above ?
2. I never used above mentioned type iterator in a program,should i need know them?
3. what extra functions we will get by using them which normal types of iterators ?
   which `set<int>::iterator it`(this kind of) cannot provide

Comment: What part of [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) didn't answer your questions ?

Comment: 1) A `set::set>::iterator` is both a bidirectional iterator and an output iterator (an actual iterator type can satisfy multiple concepts). 2)  If you don't use a particular iterator type, then arguably you don't need to know about it - but knowledge rarely hurts, say if you need to decide when *not* to use a particular type of iterator 3) Your third question is meaningless. Containers provide iterators that can sensibly iterate over themselves.  The capabilities of the iterator are determined by what makes sense for iterating over the particular container.

Answer (score 0):

`set<int>::iterator` has type `Constant LegacyBidirectionalIterator`, you can find this at site [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). 
Having a good knowledge of these iterators will benefit you, but in general we just need to know how to use it. For an iterator it's enough if you know whether it's decremental or incremental.

Answer (score 0):

C++-Reference shows this [iterator  Constant LegacyBidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). So you have a bidirectional iterator. [A LegacyBidirectionalIterator is a LegacyForwardIterator that can be moved in both directions (i.e. incremented and decremented)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator).

Answer (score 0):

**Q1** what type of iterator is that is it the iterator of some kind mentioned above?

> From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set
>
> `iterator Constant` [*LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)
> `const_iterator Constant` [*LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)

**Q2** I never used above mentioned type iterator in a program, should i need know them?

> The type is not a C++ type. It is a concept. Yes, you need to know about them to use them properly.

**Q3** what extra functions we will get by using them which normal types of iterators? which `set<int>::iterator it` (this kind of) cannot provide

> The answer to question is moot due to the answer to **Q2**.